# Get indexes of row and section with multiple sections?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I want a specific section `indexPath` but this code only give me section 0 `indexPath` because `InSection` I set 0.
if there is multiple section then how i get `indexPath`?

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
```

help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on button the below code is useful

```
-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableviewName];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.accountTablView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    NSLog(@"section index-----%ld",(long)indexPath.section);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tag` attribute on `sender` is returning it's default value.
Ensure you set the `tag` appropriately during `sender`s creation, it should be set as:

```
myView.tag = indexPath
```

Now, the `sender` will return the correct `indexPath` values while doing:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
```

Just *ensure* tag is set correctly (I'm guessing in cellForRowAtIndexpath:) to retrieve the correct indexes.